Interpreting by dividing up results of AB test
at my company we are doing AB tests (with 95% confidence) for features of our game (mobile app, hyper-casual game, Global scale).
After the tests had ran its course, we have a practice of dividing up the Global metrics into Country metrics to see if it's statistically significant. If it is significant, we roll out the feature for the countries, if not we don't.
I can't help but feeling this is a violation of some statistical rule. Seems like we are cherry picking any results that seems good to deem them good.
What do you guys think, is it a good practice for testing?

How exactly do you divide up the Global metrics into Country metrics? Are you measuring these metrics per country or only globally?

We are using firebase, so we have user-level metrics (each row of user data comes with their own Country)

OK, then how do you "divide" the metrics? Why even do that if you have per country measurements? Are you just testing out each country separately and are worried this might be overdoing it?

Ahh, sorry to mislead you, what I meant was we take a look at each country's metric individually, not adding them up then dividing them.
And yes, we are supposedly looking at metrics for every country in the world (we look at like 10 countries we consider tier-1 individually). I do think we are overdoing it and I think looking at multiple countries ought to lead us to more false positive right?

I see, then yours is a classical case of multiple testing. Classically you would solve this using some p-value correction. See Why is multiple comparison a problem?.

Thanks a lot, I have looked into the multiple comparison problem and now I know there is so much more to research :( .
